# is there any hooks or action to fire function of insert into post in media library?

Tags: media-library, wp-editor

I am seeking for help to find the action or hook in order to fire function **insert into post** in media library.
I did create a new tab for my videos and would like to insert my converted video by clicking an a tag or button to embed video into the WordPress editor.

Please help
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hook is `media_send_to_editor`.

From the source of core.

```
apply_filters (
    'media_send_to_editor',      
    string $html,
    int $send_id, 
    array $attachment
```

)

Filter the HTML markup for a media item sent to the editor.

Comment: Welcome, that's the goal of WPSE. @JoT